# Procurar rua apenas de alguma cidade + estado Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google

Estou utilizando a API de mapas da Google, e estou com uma duvida: como posso fazer para procurar uma rua apenas de uma cidade? Caso aquela rua não seja encontrada em uma determinada cidade, não aconteça nada.

Eu tenho basicamente 3 campos: um select para o estado, outro para as cidades do respectivo estado, e um campo de texto para a rua

meu código está da seguinte forma:

```
     <div class="form-group">
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Estado</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="estado" name="estado">
                    <option id="padraoEstado">Selecione um estado</option>
                    <?php 
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_estados";
                        $query = $conn->query($sql);
                        while($post = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $post['ID_state']; ?>"><?php echo $post['uf']; ?> </option>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select> 
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#estado").change(function(){
                                    $("#endereçoEmpresa").val("");
                                    $("#padraoEstado").remove();
                                    var valorEstado = $('#estado option:selected').val();
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "carregarCidades.php",
                                        type: "POST",
                                        dataType: "html",
                                        data:{
                                            valorEstado: valorEstado
                                        },
                                        success: function(data){
                                            $("#cidade").removeAttr("disabled");
                                            $("#cidade").append().html(data);
                                            var valorCidade = $('#cidade option:selected').text();
                                            $("#mapCompany").show();
                                            marker = null;
                                            initialize();
                                            codeAddress();

                                        },
                                        error: function(data){
                                            alert(data)
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                    <label>Cidade</label>
                    <select disabled class="form-control" id="cidade" name="cidade">
                    </select> 
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#cidade").change(function(){
                        $("#endereçoEmpresa").val("");
                        codeAddress();
                    });

                    $("#endereçoEmpresa").change(function(){    
                        codeAddress();
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label >Endereço da Empresa</label>
                <input type="text"  id="endereçoEmpresa" name="endereçoEmpresa" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var geocoder;
                var map;
                var marker;
                 function initialize() {
                    função para iniciar o mapa
}
    function codeAddress(){
                var valorCidade = $('#cidade option:selected').text();
                var valorEstado = $('#estado option:selected').text();
                var valorEndereco = $("#endereçoEmpresa").val();
                var address = valorEndereco + ", " + valorCidade + " - " + valorEstado;

                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR'}, function(results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                     if(!marker){
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                        }); 
                     }else{
                        marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
                     }
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng()
                    $("#lat").val(latitude);
                    $("#lng").val(longitude);
                  }else{
                    alert("A API de mapas do Google não conseguiu achar esta localização por algum motivo: " + status);
                  }
                });
              }
            </script>
```

Comment: Faça o seguinte na tua query que passa para a API: <estado>, <cidade>, <endereço>

Comment: Outra alternativa: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-component-restriction. Você pode restringir pelo cep da cidade

Answer (score 1):

Você pode restringir pelo inicio do CEP da cidade:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-component-restriction:

```
function initMap() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: {lat: -33.865, lng: 151.209}
    });

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    });
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, map) {
    geocoder.geocode({
        componentRestrictions: {
            /* Aqui seta o pais */
            country: 'br',
            /* Aqui o inicio do CEP */
            postalCode: '89235'
        }
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            window.alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' +
            status);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fala amigo!

Estávamos enfrentando o mesmo problema e acabei construindo uma solução em Javascript capaz de restringir o endereço da forma que quiser.

## O Problema

A realidade é que os métodos do Google Places API não nos dá muitas opções de restringir endereços, apenas é possível restringir, por exemplo, o país e as coordenadas geográficas (se você tiver condição de obtê-las no contexto da sua aplicação).

Porém, continua sendo meio complicado para os usuários digitarem o endereço completo (bairro, cidade, estado, etc.) todas as vezes que precisarem de um endereço validado (pelo menos no meu caso de uso que é atendimento a emergências de bombeiro).

## Solução

Não é 100% que não irá retornar resultados não desejados, mas irá poupar bastante tempo e esforço de digitação do usuário.

Basicamente esse script, por baixo dos panos, adiciona à requisição as restrições necessárias, antes de enviar para os servidores do Google, de uma forma transparente para o usuário.

É usado "service.getPlacePredictions" e "google.maps.places.AutocompleteService" e foi implementado de uma forma que o faturamento é do tipo "Autocomplete without Places Details - Per Session", o que significa que será cobrado uma única vez para todo o processo que compreende desde o início da digitação do endereço pelo usuário, até o momento em que ele clica em uma das sugestões apresentadas (a forma mais barata disponível).

Uma outra vantagem de usar esse autocomplete customizado, ao invés do widget padrão do google, é que o campo de texto com o autocomplete não será bloqueado se houver algum problema com a API Key, como limite de cotas, pagamento, etc. Assim o usuário pode digitar algum endereço e futuramente os administradores do sistema podem dar o adequado tratamento aos endereços não validados.

É necessário que o Places API e o Maps JavaScript API esteja ativado no seu console.cloud.google.com.

Enfim, abaixo é tudo o que você precisa para fazer o componente desenvolvido funcionar na sua aplicação.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
      <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>This example uses service.getPlacePredictions and google.maps.places.AutocompleteService what means that the billing stands for "Autocomplete without Places Details - Per Session"</p>
      <!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
      <form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
         <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
            <p><input id="estado" type="text" name="estado" placeholder="Estado" value="SC"></p>
            <p><input id="cidade" type="text" name="cidade" placeholder="Cidade"value="FLORIANOPOLIS"></p>
            <p><input id="bairro" type="text" name="bairro" placeholder="Bairro" value="CENTRO"></p>
            <p><input id="numero" type="text" name="numero" placeholder="Numero" value="10"></p>
            <input id="logradouro" type="text" name="logradouro" placeholder="Logradouro">
         </div>
         <input type="submit">
      </form>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_API_KEY&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="./autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         let autocomplete = new RestrictedAutocomplete(document.getElementById("logradouro"), function () {
            console.log(this.lastResultBusca);
            console.log(this.lastResultEnderecoCompleto);
            console.log(this.lastResultNumero);
            console.log(this.lastResultNumeroA);
            console.log(this.lastResultLogradouro);
            console.log(this.lastResultLogradouroA);
            console.log(this.lastResultBairro);
            console.log(this.lastResultBairroA);
            console.log(this.lastResultCidade);
            console.log(this.lastResultCidadeA);
            console.log(this.lastResultEstado);
            console.log(this.lastResultEstadoA);
            console.log(this.lastResultPais);
            console.log(this.lastResultPaisA);
            console.log(this.lastResultCEP);
            console.log(this.lastResultCEPA);
            console.log(this.lastResultId);
            console.log(this.lastResultLatitude);
            console.log(this.lastResultLongitude);
         });
         autocomplete.setRestrictions(document.getElementById("estado"), 
            document.getElementById("cidade"), 
            document.getElementById("bairro"), 
            document.getElementById("numero"));
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Autocomplete funcionando:

[image: autocomplete working]

Autocomplete após o usuário selecionar um endereço:
[image: an address has been selected]

Para mais detalhes veja o [projeto no GitHub](https://github.com/linomassarani/restricted-location-google-autocomplete/blob/master/README.md).

Espero que te ajude!